# Blender side preparing FBX export for Maya

Tags: export

There 2 conflicts when I export an FBX file to Maya that I can't find a Blender side solution. Meaning, I wish I could export the FBX to be compatible without having to repair it once imported in Maya.

1) Any names with a period "." eg: shoe.001 That particular character is replaced by a very long string once imported so I need to find a script to remove that character from all names. Or if possible to prevent it from naming duplicates with a decimal point in the first place.

2) All Bone exported from  Blender end up as tiny joints the size = 0.09 and I wish I could change them all into a 1.0 in joint size. This may have something to do with exporting settings of .1 scale.

Comment: Check this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Batch_Rename_Datablocks or this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Object_Multi_Rename or this https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-6-(Batch-Naming) to fix your names with batch renaming.

Comment: All the renaming scripts rename prefixes and suffixes ignoring the period so I need a custom script to find "." and delete.

Comment: I believe the last one linked can take care of period characters with the proper configuration i think.

Comment: I tried the last one, it can change either the prefix or suffix but not the period itself.

Comment: Yes it can I just did it, there a setting at the bottom of the *Batch Name* panel to manually choose the separator character for numbering. If that doesn't suit you, you can also use the *Batch Find and Replace* for the period character and replace it with whatever you want, if you disable the *Sort Duplicates* option at the bottom

Comment: I got it.
That is what that line at the bottom is about. Hit the "Count" grays out the numerator. The small space at the bottom right is the substitute the period if there is a numeration.